# Get value from multiple checkbox in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I get value from checkbox in php using javascript to get value by array when button proses clicked?

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: Paste your code in SO...

Comment: Also post the javascript you have already tried, I think you missed that part...

Comment: how javascript code in button proses to get value from checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

You should make the `checkbox` name as an array like this.

```
    <input class="destination" name = "destination[]" type = "checkbox" value="1"> Name1
    <input class="destination" name = "destination[]" type = "checkbox" value="2"> Name2
    <input class="destination" name = "destination[]" type = "checkbox" value="3"> Name3
    <input class="destination" name = "destination[]" type = "checkbox" value="4"> Name4
    <button id="abc">ALert Values</button>
```

In php you can get the selected value from checkbox as array like this

```
Array
(
    [destination] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
)
```

considering only `name1, name2 and name3` is selected by the user

Your javascript

```
<script>
        $("#abc").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchIDs = $(".destination:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get(); // <----
            alert(searchIDs);
        });

    </script>
```

It will alert all selected checkboxes.

Comment: thank you for answer, how can i get checkbox value when i click button proses

Comment: yes, but separated in div, ihave put class chk main in div.

Comment: ok i ll edit my answer... check that

Answer (score 1):

On client:

```
<input name = "destination_1" type = "checkbox">
<input name = "destination_2" type = "checkbox">
....
```

On server:

```
<?php
 $values = [];
 for($i = 1; $i < $maxCheckBoxCount; $i++) {
  if(isset($_POST['destination_'.$i])) {
   $values[] = $i;
  }
 }
?>
```

Then $values will be your answer;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running code sample for you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getVal()
            {
                var selected = new Array();
                 $("input:checkbox[name=destination]:checked").each(function() {
                       selected.push($(this).val());
                  });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name = "destination" type = "checkbox" value="1"> Name1
        <input name = "destination" type = "checkbox" value="2"> Name2
        <input name = "destination" type = "checkbox" value="3"> Name3
        <input name = "destination" type = "checkbox" value="4"> Name4

        <input type="button" name="btnProcess" value="Process" onclick="getVal()">
    </body>
</html>
```

You can modify it according to your needs.